# Get the Ip in use

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm a little confuse about getting the ip address of a PC. I have a winforms application running in multiples pc. The application in certain circunstances must send messages to the other apps. To do that I write to the database the infomation about the pc that is running the app, among the data is the IP Address. The idea is to use WCF to comunicate and broadcast messages to running applications.
So, the problem is how can I get the working Ip Address. Image a notebook with an ethernet ip address, a wi fi address, and a vmware address. Which of them do i have to choose?

Here is the code i use. But in the case of the notebook it is returning the vmware address, and it is useless.

```
private String GetMyIp()
{
    String ipAddress = 
      System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(
         System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
      .AddressList.First(i => i.AddressFamily.Equals(
         System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
      .ToString();
    return ipAddress;
 }
```

The main idea is to get the ip address which has a connection. Hope be clear.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Jamming all your code on one line makes it difficult to read and awkward, if not impossible, to debug.

Comment: @SteveWellens - maybe he is imitating a fluent api! :)

Comment: `First` will fail with an exception if there are no IPv4 addresses.

Comment: _"The idea is to use WCF to comunicate and broadcast messages to running applications."_ - so your client app is functioning as a WCF service? Why not let the client connect to a central WCF service?

Comment: @CodeCaster is right... why not register with clients with a single controlling service at a known endpoint. P2P client discovery is non-trivial.

Comment: Yes, I think i will consider using a single controlling service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well unless you make a connection its a lot of work for your computer to determine which card its going to use.. or did use.

Heres the way I did it.. I made a connection then asked, what it used to do it, actually I used part of your code, it certainly seems to work

Also, of course the other end of the connection can also check the remote (eg client) address in a similar manner..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    TcpClient t = new TcpClient("www.microsoft.com", 80);


    Console.WriteLine(GetMyIp(t.Client.LocalEndPoint.AddressFamily));
    t.Close();
}

static private String GetMyIp(AddressFamily addr)
{
    String ipAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(
        System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
        )
        .AddressList.First(i => i.AddressFamily.Equals(addr)).ToString();
    return ipAddress;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well, but the problem is that the production enviroment does not have an internet connection.

Comment: Well the example was of "a" connection, if you're made a connectio to your own system, you would use *that* connection not one you just made.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to consider when enumerate the active network connection. if you have wifi adapter and LAN connection and both are active , which you would like the running application to use ?

why not using a good practice of central WCF publish-subsribe method, let the running client to request the central WCF service and probably on the WCF server end to store the EndPoint address ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is a nice problem. I have to system, in one i can use e central wcf service. But in another i can not (because the system was done as i describe in the question)